# Why does an atexit handler panic when it accesses stdout?

Tags: rust, atexit

The Rust program below panics when it accesses `stdout` in the `atexit` handler.

```
extern crate libc;

extern "C" fn bye() {
    println!("bye");
}

fn main() {
    println!("hello");
    unsafe { libc::atexit(bye) };
}
```

Output:

```
hello
thread '<main>' panicked at 'cannot access stdout during shutdown', ../src/libcore/option.rs:298
fatal runtime error: Could not unwind stack, error = 5
An unknown error occurred
```

It seems to me that [this registration](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/211296ddabb6a307a0f60af1cb93f39b85ba5bbd/src/libstd/io/lazy.rs#L54) should run before our `atexit` registration, so [this line](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/211296ddabb6a307a0f60af1cb93f39b85ba5bbd/src/libstd/io/lazy.rs#L57) in the handler should run only after our custom handler. Thus it should not panic.

Comment: I ran into the same problem, although my error code was `pointer being freed was not allocated`. When replacing `println!` with `libc::printf` it works though. I agree: it seems that the rust destruction runs too early

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're confusing `libc::atexit`, which you call, and `sys_common::at_exit` (in src/libstd/sys/common/mod.rs) which your link points to and which Rust calls during early cleanup.

Those are two different cleanup queues, and I wouldn't want to rely on them being executed in a specific order.